# Replace filename with path and extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text with images without path and extension stripped down e.g to store in db:

```
 <img src="BUS-icon">
```

OR (if it has path and extension already)

```
<img src=".../images/thumbs/BUS-icon.png">
```

I need to get the filename to replace with prefix and extension (if not added already) e.g:

```
'some text <img src=".../images/thumbs/BUS-icon.png"> another text '.replace(/src=['|"](.*?)['|"]/ig
   function($1){
    var filename=$1.match(/DESIRED REGEXP/)
    return 'src="../images/thumbs/'+filename[0]+'.png"';
   }
);
```

I need the `DESIRED REGEXP` to convert following test

```
 image 1 <img src="BUS-icon1">
  image 2 <img src='BUS-icon2.png'>
  image 3 <img src="../images/thumbs/BUS-icon3.png">
  image 4 <img src='abc/BUS-icon4.png'>
```

To

```
image 1 <img src="../images/thumbs/BUS-icon1.png">
      image 2 <img src='../images/thumbs/BUS-icon2.png'>
      image 3 <img src="../images/thumbs/BUS-icon3.png">
      image 4 <img src='../images/thumbs/BUS-icon4.png'>
```

Actual application knows the filename without path and extension and replacing src with complete path.

## Edit:

```
This seems to be working so far :

text.replace(/src=['"](.*?)['"]/ig,function($1,$2){ 
  var filename=$2.match(/(?:.+\/)?([^."']+)/)[1]  
  return 'src="../images/thumbs/'+filename+'.png"';
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var filename=$1.match(/(src=['"])?(.+\/)?([^."']+)/)[3]
```

Comment: I get paths : `src="BUS-icon1"
src="BUS-icon2
BUS-icon3
BUS-icon4` it should not contains src=" I think

Comment: In that case: `var filename=$1.match(/(src=['"])?(.+\/)?([^."']+)/)[3]`
Sorry, I missed the src part

Comment: @sakhunzai this will match ../images/thumbs/BUS-icon3.png image 3 as well.but that need not be replaced as per OP

Comment: It need to match that as I need to know filename `BUS-icon3` and add prefix and suffix to it

Comment: probably wee need non-capture e.g `/(?:.+\/)?([^."']+)/`

Answer (score 2):

```
^(image\s+\d+\s*<img\s*src=["'])((?:(?!\.\.\/images|"|').)*?["']>)$
```

Try this.Replace by `$1../images/$2`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/18

Comment: @Jonny5 i know.But `image 3` was to be ignored.Dunno how the accepted answer is working

Comment: It did not mean to be ignored e.g in case `image 4 <img src='abc/BUS-icon4.png'>` I might n change the path and extension so what desired here is to extract `filename` without extension and path prefix ,thanks